# How can I make a Google Docs Add-on for personal use without a Workspace subscription?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I don't want to share it with other users, it's just a personal productivity tool.

It seems my only option is to make it available to external users (internal users is reserved for Workspace accounts), but then I'm forced through the verification process.

I've tried using the "Test Deployment" function in the script editor, but I think that can only be used to test an Add-On that is bound to document. If the Apps Script project is unbound, the test deployment succeeds, but the Add-On doesn't appear in the menu.

I suspect this isn't possible, but I'd appreciate confirmation.

Comment: Try libraries instead. You would still need to add scripts to add a simple script to every Google doc though.

Comment: Your right, is not possible. However depending on your needs you can use a library as @TheMaster suggests, a web app, or a master doc. All depends on what you need.

Comment: Thanks. I want to easily run a utility function from any Google Doc. I could put it in a library, but having to add a script to every Google Doc to call it would be too painful. I assume "master doc" means cloning a document or using a template? Unfortunately the docs I want to use the script in aren't created that way. How could I use a webapp for this purpose?

Comment: There's [tag:clasp] using [tag:google-apps-script-api], which you may use to insert a script into all your Google docs.

Comment: Use a web-app.   Have it execute as you and only you.  I've been running them for many years and I have no trouble and never been verified.  I share them with my kids by putting them on a shared drive where they are full member and they take them and set them up themselves and run them just for themselves and they have never had any trouble.

Comment: One of my scripts is for a Google Doc and I use it for writing because it creates and enhanced writing environment for me.  I save one as a template and just create a copy everytime I start another story.  It's a little more trouble than an addon but it's good for me and I can always add to it when I find something else I want to add.

Comment: Thanks all. Eventually I settled on a local Chrome plugin. I wanted something I could quickly click on, so although it's not as clean as an Add-On, it's actually quicker to find.